# Как добавить текст внутрь рамки SVG с переносом текста, как в HTML

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, svg

В сети много художественных рамок SVG например:

```html
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="320" height="320" viewBox="0 0 1280.000000 1280.000000"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" style="border:1px solid">
<g  transform="translate(0.000000,1280.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
fill="black" stroke="black">
<path  d="M1315 11443 c-269 -38 -511 -226 -622 -483 -69 -161 -64 189 -61
-4185 3 -3755 4 -3953 21 -4010 87 -294 306 -507 591 -575 79 -19 134 -20
1994 -20 l1912 0 36 33 c64 58 55 152 -19 197 -31 20 -65 20 -1907 20 -2078 0
-1948 -4 -2083 67 -130 68 -228 189 -274 338 -17 58 -18 203 -18 3985 l0 3925
24 73 c60 184 214 327 401 373 46 12 866 14 5095 14 l5040 0 75 -23 c41 -13
100 -39 131 -58 116 -70 217 -208 250 -344 12 -46 14 -696 14 -3965 0 -3705
-1 -3913 -18 -3974 -54 -197 -219 -355 -414 -396 -58 -12 -356 -15 -1951 -15
-1624 0 -1887 -2 -1911 -14 -78 -41 -88 -153 -20 -210 l31 -26 1921 0 c1885 0
1924 1 2005 20 277 66 503 285 584 566 l23 79 0 3980 0 3980 -32 95 c-87 255
-268 436 -523 523 l-95 32 -5085 1 c-2797 1 -5098 -1 -5115 -3z"/>
<path d="M5909 2812 c-275 -91 -360 -415 -180 -684 68 -101 167 -198 361 -353
171 -137 260 -220 290 -268 l17 -28 38 49 c44 58 98 107 295 264 322 257 432
418 432 633 0 143 -49 245 -157 327 -110 83 -297 104 -416 45 -67 -32 -133
-97 -166 -160 l-24 -49 -25 50 c-30 61 -109 136 -172 165 -66 30 -215 34 -293
9z"/>
</g> 
</svg>
```

Или вот такая рамка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пробовал добавлять текст внутрь рамки с помощью команды SVG `<text>`, но нужно на каждую строчку высчитывать абсолютные координаты начала первого символа.  Автоматического переноса текста нет, как в HTML, когда строка не укладывается по ширине рамки.

Есть конечно теги `<tspan dx="0" dy="10" >` внутри тегов `<text>`, но это тоже неудобно.

Как добавить текст внутрь рамки SVG с переносом текста, как в HTML?

Answer (score 3):

Проблему переноса текста в SVG помогает решать [foreignObject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject)

***Структура файла SVG с встроенным foreignObject***

```
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="75%" height="75%" viewBox="0 0 1280 539">
 <style>
 Стили для svg
 Стили для тегов HTML внутри foreignObject
 </style>
  <g>
   код SVG 
   <path ....>
   </path>
   <circle ... />
  </g>
  <foreignObject  x="100" y="180" width="1080" height="800">
   код HTML
   <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> Обязательно указать namespace 
   </div
 </svg>
```

Получился текст с автоматическим переносом строк  внутри рамки SVG
Если высота текста превышает высоту рамки, то появится **полоса прокрутки**

```html
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="640" height="640" viewBox="0 0 1280.000000 1280.000000"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" style="background:gold">
 <style>
   

    div {
      background:#5F5F5F;
      color: white;
      font-size:48px;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: auto;
      padding:1em;
          
    }
  </style>

<g transform="translate(0.000000,1280.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
fill="#000000" stroke="none">
<path d="M1315 11443 c-269 -38 -511 -226 -622 -483 -69 -161 -64 189 -61
-4185 3 -3755 4 -3953 21 -4010 87 -294 306 -507 591 -575 79 -19 134 -20
1994 -20 l1912 0 36 33 c64 58 55 152 -19 197 -31 20 -65 20 -1907 20 -2078 0
-1948 -4 -2083 67 -130 68 -228 189 -274 338 -17 58 -18 203 -18 3985 l0 3925
24 73 c60 184 214 327 401 373 46 12 866 14 5095 14 l5040 0 75 -23 c41 -13
100 -39 131 -58 116 -70 217 -208 250 -344 12 -46 14 -696 14 -3965 0 -3705
-1 -3913 -18 -3974 -54 -197 -219 -355 -414 -396 -58 -12 -356 -15 -1951 -15
-1624 0 -1887 -2 -1911 -14 -78 -41 -88 -153 -20 -210 l31 -26 1921 0 c1885 0
1924 1 2005 20 277 66 503 285 584 566 l23 79 0 3980 0 3980 -32 95 c-87 255
-268 436 -523 523 l-95 32 -5085 1 c-2797 1 -5098 -1 -5115 -3z"/>
<path d="M5909 2812 c-275 -91 -360 -415 -180 -684 68 -101 167 -198 361 -353
171 -137 260 -220 290 -268 l17 -28 38 49 c44 58 98 107 295 264 322 257 432
418 432 633 0 143 -49 245 -157 327 -110 83 -297 104 -416 45 -67 -32 -133
-97 -166 -160 l-24 -49 -25 50 c-30 61 -109 136 -172 165 -66 30 -215 34 -293
9z"/>
</g> 

<foreignObject
      x="100" y="180" width="1080" height="800"
      transform="translate(0,0)" > 
     <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla posuere non enim vitae tincidunt. Quisque eleifend, lectus a rhoncus cursus, libero risus condimentum ipsum, vitae finibus dolor metus eget turpis.   Mauris vitae elementum sem. Aliquam urna ligula, pretium eu lorem non, dapibus dignissim lorem. Integer tempor tempus ex, a egestas lectus condimentum sed. Suspendisse tellus sem, placerat ac malesuada sed,  tincidunt placerat eros. Proin id justo vitae nibh aliquam consectetur at eu leo. Praesent eleifend facilisis libero at cursus.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla posuere non enim vitae tincidunt. Quisque eleifend, lectus a rhoncus cursus, libero risus condimentum ipsum, vitae finibus dolor metus eget turpis.   Mauris vitae elementum sem.  Aliquam urna ligula, pretium eu lorem non, dapibus dignissim lorem. Integer tempor tempus ex, a egestas lectus condimentum sed. Suspendisse tellus sem, placerat ac malesuada sed,  tincidunt placerat eros. Proin id justo vitae nibh aliquam consectetur at eu leo. Praesent eleifend facilisis libero at cursus. </div>  
</foreignObject>     
 
</svg>
```

*Другой пример художественной рамки*

```html
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="75%" height="75%" viewBox="0 0 1280 539"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" style="background:#111111">
 <style>
      div {
      background:#111111;
      color: white;
      font:36px serif;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: auto;
      padding:1em;
        }
  </style>

<g transform="translate(0.000000,539.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000) "
fill="white" stroke="none">
<path d="M965 5283 c-49 -25 -82 -62 -105 -116 -19 -43 -22 -65 -18 -138 4
-79 9 -97 46 -173 56 -111 129 -179 266 -246 l98 -48 -68 -11 c-266 -47 -485
-237 -572 -499 -23 -69 -26 -93 -26 -232 -1 -178 9 -226 81 -380 57 -123 125
-212 298 -390 165 -170 236 -252 294 -336 54 -81 107 -197 126 -276 15 -65 21
-203 8 -196 -96 49 -110 53 -189 53 -73 0 -88 -4 -150 -35 -122 -63 -191 -177
-201 -336 -16 -242 117 -453 349 -552 57 -24 74 -27 193 -27 118 0 136 3 193
26 34 15 62 24 62 21 0 -3 -11 -19 -24 -36 -54 -72 -203 -319 -247 -411 -75
-157 -102 -258 -105 -396 -3 -100 0 -127 21 -194 51 -168 162 -265 300 -265
49 0 131 37 167 76 65 70 87 187 49 269 -16 35 -108 131 -117 122 -2 -2 2 -19
8 -39 23 -77 -17 -153 -97 -184 -146 -55 -255 85 -233 300 19 185 82 324 290
636 150 225 245 397 278 505 46 149 46 368 -1 536 -26 95 -93 237 -162 341
-72 112 -315 418 -330 418 -7 0 -22 -8 -35 -18 l-23 -18 112 -149 c232 -311
327 -491 360 -679 16 -92 7 -295 -16 -361 -70 -205 -187 -323 -352 -355 -175
-35 -357 51 -433 203 -76 153 -3 317 142 317 98 0 142 -47 143 -150 0 -36 -4
-78 -8 -93 -7 -26 -6 -28 15 -22 36 11 86 53 113 94 14 21 34 78 46 132 41
183 8 406 -91 615 -84 179 -180 307 -410 549 -78 83 -163 181 -188 219 -161
245 -186 545 -65 767 59 109 203 211 338 240 86 18 249 15 321 -6 195 -56 330
-203 338 -367 7 -139 -67 -248 -169 -248 -41 0 -102 37 -130 77 -62 92 -1 232
110 250 35 6 35 6 18 26 -65 73 -196 58 -297 -34 -102 -93 -150 -223 -148
-404 1 -159 39 -281 139 -447 19 -32 37 -58 41 -58 4 0 18 9 31 19 l23 18 -51
104 c-53 109 -75 187 -86 304 l-7 70 53 -57 c111 -117 262 -145 409 -75 28 13
50 23 50 21 0 -1 -19 -35 -41 -76 -94 -166 -210 -277 -402 -382 -59 -32 -107
-61 -107 -64 0 -3 7 -13 16 -23 15 -16 20 -15 92 24 42 22 104 59 137 81 84
56 261 231 328 324 185 257 240 536 152 762 -72 185 -170 283 -509 508 -292
195 -339 242 -354 360 -10 73 8 131 54 171 l34 30 -29 16 c-38 19 -108 19
-146 -2z"/>
<path d="M11694 5290 c-34 -13 -36 -26 -9 -44 67 -44 86 -165 41 -254 -38 -74
-115 -139 -329 -281 -109 -72 -232 -159 -273 -192 -130 -108 -218 -234 -260
-375 -28 -90 -25 -265 5 -369 52 -181 156 -349 312 -505 102 -102 171 -154
294 -223 92 -52 101 -55 117 -40 10 9 18 20 18 24 0 4 -44 31 -97 59 -54 29
-118 66 -143 83 -74 50 -202 188 -252 273 -68 114 -68 116 -11 88 99 -49 204
-51 307 -6 43 20 115 82 134 117 18 34 22 12 12 -82 -11 -102 -49 -218 -104
-317 l-34 -62 30 -17 c17 -10 34 -14 39 -10 25 28 111 195 134 265 24 69 29
104 33 213 5 152 -9 224 -64 322 -94 168 -286 237 -378 134 -19 -21 -19 -21 3
-21 70 0 151 -87 151 -162 0 -81 -80 -168 -154 -168 -147 0 -222 209 -137 379
58 115 161 194 306 236 71 21 234 24 320 6 130 -28 256 -113 325 -221 127
-199 115 -507 -30 -752 -24 -40 -107 -138 -202 -240 -192 -206 -267 -299 -351
-434 -120 -193 -183 -414 -174 -614 3 -58 7 -114 10 -125 19 -77 30 -107 57
-143 46 -64 144 -122 125 -75 -32 82 -16 184 36 227 25 21 41 26 88 26 200 0
247 -261 75 -420 -125 -115 -310 -141 -463 -64 -110 55 -185 147 -238 295 -38
107 -45 300 -14 432 41 177 124 327 336 614 114 154 123 169 107 181 -44 34
-42 36 -187 -150 -77 -99 -161 -212 -187 -250 -86 -128 -149 -278 -179 -423
-17 -79 -16 -305 0 -380 31 -141 114 -299 310 -595 75 -113 153 -237 173 -276
114 -218 140 -457 62 -576 -27 -42 -88 -78 -131 -78 -40 1 -106 33 -131 65
-28 35 -37 88 -24 133 6 20 10 37 8 39 -8 9 -99 -85 -118 -121 -25 -48 -26
-135 -2 -191 22 -55 79 -110 136 -135 162 -70 334 53 393 281 17 63 17 221 1
290 -39 172 -131 357 -308 621 -32 48 -58 89 -58 91 0 3 28 -7 63 -21 56 -24
75 -27 187 -27 105 0 134 4 185 23 232 87 383 323 362 566 -25 279 -274 443
-497 328 l-62 -31 7 77 c21 247 109 400 410 711 192 198 271 301 332 429 76
159 102 353 69 524 -57 295 -294 527 -592 579 l-67 12 103 50 c135 66 213 140
267 253 36 75 38 84 38 179 0 108 -15 154 -67 202 -49 46 -139 66 -194 43z"/>
<path d="M3628 5123 l-2098 -3 18 -28 c42 -68 122 -139 312 -277 127 -92 179
-142 264 -255 108 -144 188 -320 217 -480 16 -88 16 -278 0 -370 -38 -216
-170 -456 -333 -606 l-45 -42 31 -43 c104 -145 235 -401 286 -557 54 -168 73
-281 73 -447 0 -172 -9 -235 -59 -393 -39 -121 -89 -212 -212 -387 -81 -115
-134 -212 -157 -287 l-17 -53 89 -90 c119 -121 181 -248 199 -405 l7 -60 4198
0 4199 0 0 33 c1 153 115 378 241 473 45 35 50 42 45 69 -12 60 -86 195 -198
361 -151 224 -211 368 -238 574 -44 345 79 766 333 1137 l49 73 -98 103 c-103
108 -163 199 -213 324 -116 289 -103 616 37 893 103 205 233 342 532 557 97
70 154 126 169 166 l11 27 -2773 -2 c-1524 -2 -3716 -4 -4869 -5z m7017 -296
c-193 -198 -317 -421 -371 -668 -25 -115 -30 -342 -10 -477 32 -214 157 -487
284 -617 l29 -30 -38 -62 c-113 -185 -218 -453 -261 -668 -30 -148 -32 -455
-5 -585 44 -203 111 -352 259 -570 58 -85 110 -164 116 -176 9 -18 2 -31 -52
-98 -69 -84 -140 -217 -159 -296 l-12 -50 -4024 2 -4024 3 -24 69 c-12 38 -39
101 -58 139 -36 70 -126 192 -147 199 -16 6 10 51 137 238 119 177 160 254
205 389 74 221 82 521 20 791 -41 179 -135 415 -229 575 l-58 99 34 46 c144
193 223 357 264 552 32 147 32 391 1 535 -58 270 -181 486 -383 677 l-92 86
4349 0 4349 0 -100 -103z"/>
<path d="M855 2887 c-442 -194 -669 -375 -746 -595 -57 -161 -3 -333 123 -396
103 -51 231 -26 310 62 37 41 73 100 65 108 -2 2 -18 -1 -36 -7 -69 -24 -161
14 -196 82 -46 88 -37 190 26 294 93 153 244 273 527 414 95 48 101 53 90 71
-7 11 -20 20 -28 20 -8 -1 -69 -24 -135 -53z"/>
<path d="M11780 2920 c-10 -18 -1 -24 97 -74 296 -148 460 -285 542 -450 74
-150 14 -325 -118 -343 -22 -3 -54 0 -72 6 -18 6 -34 9 -36 7 -9 -9 20 -60 59
-102 141 -153 367 -115 439 75 23 62 27 155 8 226 -50 187 -244 372 -553 527
-138 69 -319 148 -341 148 -8 0 -19 -9 -25 -20z"/>
</g>

<foreignObject
      x="270" y="70" width="740" height="400"> 
     <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla posuere non enim vitae tincidunt. Quisque eleifend, lectus a rhoncus cursus, libero risus condimentum ipsum, vitae finibus dolor metus eget turpis.   Mauris vitae elementum sem. Aliquam urna ligula, pretium eu lorem non, dapibus dignissim lorem. Integer tempor tempus ex, a egestas lectus condimentum sed. Suspendisse tellus sem, placerat ac malesuada sed,  tincidunt placerat eros. Proin id justo vitae nibh aliquam consectetur at eu leo. Praesent eleifend facilisis libero at cursus.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla posuere non enim vitae tincidunt. Quisque eleifend, lectus a rhoncus cursus, libero risus condimentum ipsum, vitae finibus dolor metus eget turpis.   Mauris vitae elementum sem.  Aliquam urna ligula, pretium eu lorem non, dapibus dignissim lorem. Integer tempor tempus ex, a egestas lectus condimentum sed. Suspendisse tellus sem, placerat ac malesuada sed,  tincidunt placerat eros. Proin id justo vitae nibh aliquam consectetur at eu leo. Praesent eleifend facilisis libero at cursus. </div>  
</foreignObject>     
 </svg>
```